# Set object's `visible` to `true` when a `tap` event is performed then set it back to `false`

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have an object as `MovieClip` and I have a button as `Button` on my flash timeline.

When the button is tapped, I want to set the `object.visible` to true then when the button is not tapped, I want to set it back to false.

How can I do that?

I have tried this code, but it won't works as I want. I only can show the object but cannot hide it back.

```
button1.addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_TAP, touchTap);

function touchTap(e:TouchEvent): void {
    mcObj.visible = true;
    stage.addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_END, touchEnd);
}

function touchEnd(e:TouchEvent): void {
   mcObj.visible = false;
   stage.removeEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_END, touchEnd);
}
```

Comment: How about change `stage.addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_END, touchEnd);` to `button1.addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_END, touchEnd);` ?

Comment: It shows me the same result

Comment: How about use TOUCH_BEGIN instead TOUCH_TAP ?
`button1.addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_BEGIN, touchTap);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before saying anything about your problem, let's take a look on the definitions of the `TouchEvent.TOUCH_BEGIN`, `TouchEvent.TOUCH_END` and `TouchEvent.TOUCH_TAP` events :

- The [`TouchEvent.TOUCH_BEGIN`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/InteractiveObject.html#event:touchBegin) is :

> Dispatched when **the user first contacts a touch-enabled device** ...

- The [`TouchEvent.TOUCH_END`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/InteractiveObject.html#event:touchEnd) is :

> Dispatched when **the user removes contact with a touch-enabled device** ...

- The [`TouchEvent.TOUCH_TAP`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/InteractiveObject.html#event:touchTap) is :

> Dispatched when **the user lifts the point of contact over the same InteractiveObject instance on which the contact was initiated on a touch-enabled device** ...

And with some tests, we can see that the `TouchEvent.TOUCH_END` event is, in almost cases, fired **before** the `TouchEvent.TOUCH_TAP` one (by 1 or 2 milliseconds), so we can understand the we are able to detect if the user has already removed contact with the device (`TouchEvent.TOUCH_END` is fired) **then** if that was on the same `InteractiveObject` object on which the contact was initiated (`TouchEvent.TOUCH_TAP` is fired).

And that's why your code is not working.

---

Now, let's see your problem : you want to show a MovieClip just when your user tap a button and hide it when he releases that button but only for a very short time (the time of a tap ~= 300 milliseconds).

In this case, I recommend you to use a `TouchEvent.TOUCH_BEGIN` event listener with a timeout to hide that object even if your user didn't release the button.

For that, take this example :

```
Multitouch.inputMode = MultitouchInputMode.TOUCH_POINT;

btn.addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_BEGIN, on_touchBegin);
function on_touchBegin(e:TouchEvent): void 
{
    obj.visible = true;
    hide_obj();
}

function hide_obj(): void 
{
    // you can use a Timer object instead of setTimeout()
    var timeout:int = setTimeout(function(){
        clearTimeout(timeout);
        obj.visible = false;
    }, 300);    
}
```

Hope that can help.

Answer (score 2):

I think this code could work.

```
button1.addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_BEGIN, touchTap);

function touchTap(e:TouchEvent): void {
    mcObj.visible = true;
    button1.addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_END, touchEnd);
}

function touchEnd(e:TouchEvent): void {
   mcObj.visible = false;
   button1.removeEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_END, touchEnd);
}
```

I changed
1: `TouchEvent.TOUCH_TAP` to `TouchEvent.TOUCH_BEGIN`
2: `stage.addEventListener` to `button1.addEventListener`

Comment: I know it will works. But not as I wanted before. If I use `TOUCH_BEGIN` and `TOUCH_END` events, there's possibility that I can touch the button for a longer time and the object's visible will stay true until I release my touch. I just need a tap.

Comment: @G.Chiko, is that not what you wanted? **"_When the button is tapped, I want to set the object.visible to true then when the button is not tapped, I want to set it back to false_"**. You use the word "tap" but your issue is described like "touch". Do you want something visible for just 1 second (tap duration) or until you release (touch duration) or you want toggle (on/off per tap)?

Comment: It'll be kind of like duration, I use tap while it's different with touch_begin - touch_end